# Populate and execute callbacks from array class attribute

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

I've recently started learning C++/Arduino and am working on abstracting some of my Arduino code in order to keep it more manageable.
I'm trying to construct a class with 2 arrays as attributes on it, one to store strings that represent commands, and a second one to store pointers to those functions.

The below code *works* (compiles), but when uploaded to the device both the `listen` and `execute` functions don't appear to work. I've searched around quite a lot, but can't find where I've gone wrong.

```cpp
/* main.ino */

// SETUP
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
SoftwareSerial bt(btRx, btTx);

#include "CMD.h"
const int cmdMax = 6;
ArriCMD cmd;

// COMMANDS
void cmdStatus()
{
  Serial.println("OK");
}

// START
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  bt.begin(9600);
  
  cmd.add("AH+STAT", cmdStatus);
}

void loop()
{
  cmd.listen(bt);
}
```

```cpp
/* ArriCMD.h */

#ifndef ArriCMD_h
#define ArriCMD_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"

class ArriCMD
{
  public:
    ArriCMD();
    void add(String cmd, void (*cb)());
    void listen(SoftwareSerial serial);
    void execute(String cmd);

  private:
    int _max = 16;
    int _amt = 0;
    String _cmds[16];
    void (*_cbs[16])();
};
```

```cpp
/* ArriCMD.cpp */

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include "ArriCMD.h"

ArriCMD::ArriCMD()
{
  //
}

void ArriCMD::add(String cmd, void (*cb)())
{
  if (_amt < _max) {
    _cmds[_amt] = cmd;
    _cbs[_amt] = *cb;
  }
}

void ArriCMD::listen(SoftwareSerial serial)
{
  if (serial.available()) {
    String cmd = serial.readString();
    Serial.print(cmd);
    execute(cmd);
  }
}

void ArriCMD::execute(String cmd)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < _amt; i++) {
    if (cmd == _cmds[i]) {
      _cbs[i]();
    }
  }
}
```

While I've been programming for over a decade, C++ and microcontrollers are brand new to me, any and all help here would be hugely appreciated.

I do intend to open source these libraries, and the subsequent platforms they're built for, once I'm more comfortable with my code quality.

Comment: For anyone reading later. The problem was that the `listen` method wasn't actually "listening", and needed to be passed in as a reference `void listen(SoftwareSerial &serial);`. I also, as @pptaszni pointed out, needed to increment my counter. It's not yet as clean as I would like, but it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to increment your commands counter `_amt`

```
void ArriCMD::add(String cmd, void (*cb)())
{
  if (_amt < _max) {
    _cmds[_amt] = cmd;
    _cbs[_amt] = *cb;
    _amt++;  // <-- here, don't you need it?
  }
}
```

Apart from that, is there some particular reason for using raw array and raw function pointers in your code? I do not use Arduino, so I am not sure, but maybe this solution is a bit cleaner:

```
class ArriCMD
{
  public:
    ArriCMD();
    void add(String cmd, std::function<void()> cb);
    void listen(SoftwareSerial serial);
    void execute(String cmd);

  private:
    std::map<String, std::function<void()> > _cmdMap;
};
```

Comment: Absolutely correct on the first point, I overlooked that in some refactoring I believe, which would have mean I was overwriting some data, but it should at least have still been listening to data on the `listen` function.

As for the latter, I ended up with this quite messy approach having a static array length after trying many other ways of dynamically having the data. I'm trying the `std::function` approach, but I'm running into a number of errors with that as well. The first of which is `error: 'std::function' has not been declared` which is from the header declaration of `add()`.

Comment: If you don't see any prints from `Serial.print(cmd);` from `listen` function, then indeed sth else somewhere else is also wrong, but I am not able to check that. For the error you need to `#include <functional>`. If Arduino compiler supports it, but I have seen other people using it.

Comment: I'm not sure the name of the operator, but prefixing the `serial` with an ampersand seems to work, I suspected it wasn't passing a reference, but just copying a SoftwareSerial instance that hadn't "begun" yet. That combined with your `_amt++` increment has fixed it! Thanks for your help!